# yt gem for youtube api using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, rubygems

How to setup `yt gem` youtube api for rails? I am facing error `"Error: invalid_request.Missing required parameter: scope"`. I have already added scope in my program here is a sample code I did.

```
This is my controller side..
request = Yt::Account.new(scopes: "youtube" ,redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/youtube_callback").authentication_url
```

*This is my yt.rb file initializer:*

```
Yt.configure do |config|  
config.log_level = :debug 
config.client_id = 'id'
config.client_secret = 'secret'


end
```

Can anyone site an example how to setup completely yt gem for rails.

*I'm using `gem 'yt', '~> 0.25.6'`*

Any idea is highly appreciated, I am a newbie in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1):

the scope needs to be formatted this way ["youtube"]. So change it to:

```
request = Yt::Account.new(scopes: ["youtube"], redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/youtube_callback").authentication_url
```

Comment: you can see what I have working so far here: https://github.com/mailethiesen/youtube-content-auditor-2